# mongodb performance related parameter

Tags: mysql, mongodb

Actually I am a MYSQL guy and now we are moving to mongodb, I will be very thankful, if someone help me to get information regarding important server variables which can impact on mongodb performance (like `innodb_buffer_pool_size, query_cache, tmp_table_size, join_buffer, sort_buffer` etc. in mysql innodb).

I searched a lot on net but unfortunately could not get specific about this topic. Here I am not asking about any specific problem but which parameters should be taken care at the time of mongodb server setup for one primary, one secondary and one arbiter.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

```
#conf file
storageEngine=mmapv1 #as using 3.2 and here default is wiredtiger.
port=27017
dbpath=/path/mongodb
logpath=/path/mongodb/mongod.log
logappend=true
fork=true
replSet=abc
oplogSize=1024
auth=true
keyFile=/path/mongodb-keyfile
profile=1
slowms=2000
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

Some basic ideas of how to go about Optimising Mongodb are giving here.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/info-mongodb-com/MongoDB-Performance-Considerations_2.4.pdf

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/administration/optimization/

Parameter references are here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/

Comment: first of all thanks for your prompt response, actually I have already read most of these documents but it will be helpful me if based on your experiance, you can list some most important parameters which should be in mongod.conf file at the time of server setup. I am sharing my conf file in my main post, please check and suggest me what parameters I should add in my conf file to keep my suppose 80 GB db size.